# Excel: A mark (eg. tick) on a matrix table will be auto-populated in another table

Tags: excel, excel-formula

```
User   Roles   Project
       1 2 3    1 2 3
A        X        X
B      X   X        X 
C        X      X X

User  Role  Project
A       2      2
B     1 & 3    3 
C       2     1&2
```

I wonder if this' even possible? Im playing with the IF and VLOOKUP function however to no avail. If it's not even possible, feel free to suggest any other arrangements. The final objective is to show the table below. Any gurus please? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: If the dataset in question is in reality of that size, then you could do this with worksheet formulas. If, however, it's actually much larger than the example you give, so that any one person may have more than two Projects or Roles, then you will require some VBA, since concatenating values into a single cell using worksheet formulas quickly becomes unfeasible if the number of strings to be concatenated is potentially any larger than, say, 3. Unless, of course, your Role and Project Names are genuinely single-digit numbers, in which case a workaround is possible.

Comment: Thanks XOR LX. May I know the possible formulae please? Im not familiar with VBA so probably will give formula a go first.

Comment: That depends. Do you mean just for the small dataset above? If so, can you confirm the ranges that each of those tables occupy? Also, you will need to specify an upper limit on the number of Roles and Projects that any one person can have. In the above it appear to be 2 - can you confirm this? This is the downside to the formula-based approach, since each string to be concatenated must come from a separate clause within the formula. And remember: this will not necessarily be extendable to larger ranges. Are you sure you understand what I'm saying?

Comment: It's actually larger but I was thinking that we can start small and probably extrapolate from there as I can use a head start for now seeing I dont have any starting point for the time being. I'll continue to read up on the VBA as you pointed out in the mean time. Thanks again XOR LX, youve been a great help :)

Comment: But that's exactly what I've been trying to tell you. The sort of set-up required involving formulas alone is not amenable to being "extrapolated" easily to larger datasets. Even if you could specify an upper bound on the maximum number of Roles or Projects that any one person can have, you'd still be in a position where you'd have to construct unfeasibly-long formulas. It would be far easier if instead you were content with a results table which had several columns to house the returns, e.g. Role1, Role2,... etc. That IS straightforward with formulas, but concatenating into single cells...

Comment: I see. Thanks for the enlightenment. As the moment I can make do with a limited range of datasets. When it grew larger I'll then look into other alternatives like the VBA which youve recommended. May I know the formulae for the concatenation that youve just mentioned please? Let's just take these limited datasets as an example :)

Comment: Ok. Can you confirm the range references for the two tables in your example? And also answer my question re an upper limit on the number of Roles and Projects that any one person can have? Is it 2? 3?

Comment: Sorry but Im unsure of the term 'range reference'. Im guessing the width and length of the table? If that's the case let's take 7x4 for the first table and 3X4 for the second. As to the upper limit let's take 2 as per the example above

Comment: I meant what actual cells do each of them occupy in your worksheet?

Comment: Table 1 :

User = B2-B3, User A = B4, User B = B5, User C = B6
Roles = C2-E2, Roles 1 = C3, Roles 2 = D3, Roles 3 = E3
Project = F2-H2, Project 1 = F3, Project 2 = G3, Project 3 = H3
X for User A = D4, G4; X for User B = C5, E5, H5; X for User C = D6, F6

Table 2 :

User = J2, User A = J3, User B = J4, User C = J5
Role = K2, Role A = K3, Role B = K4, Role C = K5
Project = L2, Project A = L3, Project B = L4, Project C = L5

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will the Users in the results table always be precisely the same as those in the source table? Also, will they always appear in precisely the same order in both?

Comment: For a moment I was worried it was a little too scattered. Glad you're ok with it. Yes it will be precisely be the same and in the same order as well

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Excel 2007 or later, these are both **array formulas****:

In K3:

=IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$E$3,,SMALL(IF($C4:$E4="X",COLUMN($C4:$E4)-MIN(COLUMN($C4:$E4))+1),1)),"")&IFERROR("&"&INDEX($C$3:$E$3,,SMALL(IF($C4:$E4="X",COLUMN($C4:$E4)-MIN(COLUMN($C4:$E4))+1),2)),"")

In L3:

=IFERROR(INDEX($F$3:$H$3,,SMALL(IF($F4:$H4="X",COLUMN($F4:$H4)-MIN(COLUMN($F4:$H4))+1),1)),"")&IFERROR("&"&INDEX($F$3:$H$3,,SMALL(IF($F4:$H4="X",COLUMN($F4:$H4)-MIN(COLUMN($F4:$H4))+1),2)),"")

Copy both down as required.

I hope you can see now how hopelessly inefficient a set-up this is. And that's just to cope with a maximum of two possible returns. For each additional potential return, another clause equivalent to that beginning with IFERROR and ending with "" would be required.

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*